# How to activate, move and resize a window in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have a window of which I know only the title (e.g. Notepad) that I need to activate, resize and place in the top-left corner of my screen.
So after some research on MSDN and forums I found some functions that should achieve this. I use FindWindow to get the handle by title, then I use GetWindowPlacement to see if notepad is minimized or not (if not, then I just use AppActivate, only need to activate it if it's not minimized). If the window is minimized however, I then try to use SetWindowPlacement to activate, resize and move it in one command.
Here is my code:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow( _
 ByVal lpClassName As String, _
 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowPlacement(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowPlacement(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Boolean
End Function

Private Structure RECT
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal X2 As Integer, ByVal Y2 As Integer)
        Me.Left = X
        Me.Top = Y
        Me.Right = X2
        Me.Bottom = Y2
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Structure WINDOWPLACEMENT
    Public Length As Integer
    Public flags As Integer
    Public showCmd As ShowWindowCommands
    Public ptMinPosition As POINTAPI
    Public ptMaxPosition As POINTAPI
    Public rcNormalPosition As RECT
End Structure

Enum ShowWindowCommands As Integer
    Hide = 0
    Normal = 1
    ShowMinimized = 2
    Maximize = 3  
    ShowMaximized = 3
    ShowNoActivate = 4
    Show = 5
    Minimize = 6
    ShowMinNoActive = 7
    ShowNA = 8
    Restore = 9
    ShowDefault = 10
    ForceMinimize = 11
End Enum

Public Structure POINTAPI
    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        Me.X = X
        Me.Y = Y
    End Sub
End Structure
```

With the actual execution being here:

```
Dim wp As WINDOWPLACEMENT
wp.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(wp)
GetWindowPlacement(FindWindow(Nothing, "Notepad"), wp)
If wp.showCmd = ShowWindowCommands.ShowMinimized Then
    Dim wp2 As WINDOWPLACEMENT
    wp2.showCmd = ShowWindowCommands.ShowMaximized
    wp2.ptMinPosition = wp.ptMinPosition
    wp2.ptMaxPosition = New POINTAPI(0, 0)
    wp2.rcNormalPosition = New RECT(0, 0, 816, 639) 'this is the size I want
    wp2.flags = wp.flags
    wp2.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(wp2)
    SetWindowPlacement(FindWindow(Nothing, "Notepad"), wp2)
    Else
        AppActivate("Notepad")
```

So I try running this but it just activates the window, while the rectangle is supposed to also resize it. So what am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to achieve all of this? Sorry for the lengthy post

Comment: With your code, the effects of the rectangle will take place after you restore the window from `maximized` to `normal`. Change `wp2.showCmd = ShowWindowCommands.ShowMaximized` to `wp2.showCmd = ShowWindowCommands.Normal`. You dont want the window to be maximized.

Comment: You neglect error checking

Answer (score 3):

I had to do a similar thing, and used the SetWindowPos function from user32.dll

Here's a vb.net implementation:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class HookUtil

    Public Const SWP_NOMOVE As Short = &H2
    Public Const SWP_NOSIZE As Short = 1
    Public Const SWP_NOZORDER As Short = &H4
    Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW As Short = &H40
    Shared ReadOnly HWND_BOTTOM As IntPtr = New IntPtr(1)

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowPos")> _
    Public Shared Function SetWindowPos( _
 hWnd As IntPtr, _
 hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, _
 x As Int32, y As Int32, cx As Int32, cy As Int32, wFlags As Int32) As IntPtr
    End Function


    Public Shared Sub HookWindow()

        Dim Processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")

        For Each p As Process In Processes

            Dim handle As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle
            If handle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 200, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

You call it with:

```
HookUtil.HookWindow()
```

Here's a C# implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace csharpsandbox

{
    public class HookUtil
    {
        // hooks window handle and repositions to specified coords

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        const short SWP_NOMOVE = 0X2;
        const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
        const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

        public static void HookWindow()
        {

            Process[] parray = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            foreach (Process p in parray)
            {
                IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 200, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

You call it with:

```
HookUtil.HookWindow();
```

Obviously the values here (process name, x,y coordinates) are hard-coded. To make this more useful you'd want to make those settable.